# joomla 3.3 make newsflash module target articles by id

Tags: joomla, module, embed, joomla3.3

I am working with Joomla 3.3 and need to show an article in a module position by ID. I found that the native "newsflash" module is better than all article embed extensions.
The only problem is, is that it only works from a category.

I want to target a single article and need to duplicate this module and edit it so that I can choose whether to show a single or multiple articles.

I tried to figure it out using  `$id = (int) $params->get('id', 0);` but I've no idea where to implement it.

Can somebody suggest a general direction of doing it?

Comment: I totally agree that mod_newsflash is the way to go. It already lets you select how many articles to show. One way to use it is if you are not using featuring in that category elsewhere, you can just feature the article and tell newsflash to only display featured. Of course you can also just put your article in a category by itself and you can also use the ordering choices and make your article the first.  Otherwise I'd just make a copy of mod_newsflash and add the article id as a parameter. It really depends on how customized you want it and how much you want it to be flexible.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. i prefer the second option. but i do not seem to understand how to add a parameter correctly :( , it will be great if you can point me to and article or tutorial than can show me the approach in general.  agian , thanks, Yonatan